# Most efficient allocation algorithm

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, integer-programming

There are $5$ customers $A, B, C, D, E$ in a shop looking to buy $35$ oranges in total.

$A$ wants to buy $5$ oranges

$B$ wants to buy $2$ oranges

$C$ wants to buy $15$ oranges

$D$ wants to buy $3$ oranges

$E$ wants to buy $10$ oranges

The shop does have $35$ oranges to sell but they have been bought in different prices (and hence need to be sold at different prices). There are $6$ different price categories:

$1$ orange of $O_1$ type that costs $\$16$

$2$ orange of $O_2$ type that costs $\$16.1$

$7$ orange of $O_3$ type that costs $\$16.2$

$10$ orange of $O_4$ type that costs $\$16.3$

$14$ orange of $O_5$ type that costs $\$16.4$

$1$ orange of $O_6$ type that costs $\$17$

The shopkeeper now needs to decide what is a "fair" way (algorithm) to allocate those oranges to his customers. There is no distinction between oranges of different price (all look th same).

I put it into Excel Sover and tried to minimize the Objective function: sum of squared disctances from the weighted average price, given the constraints we have (Integer Programming).

However, I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, since if we increase the number of oranges or different prices the system gets too big.

Would you have any idea on how to approach that?

Comment: Surely the shopkeeper would want to sell as many (15) expensive oranges $O_6$ first to $C$ then the next 10 most expensive $O_5$ to $E$ and then all the $O_4$ to $A$... and so on. The people who demand the most pay more. That makes sense if you've ever seen a market depth chart.

Comment: I see your point, it makes sense - increasing demand drives prices up. This is another, interesting way to approach "fair" though. Now, I would be more interested in allocating those oranges so the discrepancies from each other's price are minimized (act as their demand for oranges did not actually move the orange price - could be oranges from different varieties).

Comment: Do we know how many of each orange type does the shop have? Is it also 35 in total? If not, there would be a collision of interests between being fair to these 5 customers and being fair to whomever comes afterwards

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I modified the problem above; we have 35 oranges in total and focus our intereste only on those, we do not care about other customers. The goal is to find a fair allocation algorithm among those 5 customers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single best / fairest objective function, but I would lean toward minimizing either the highest average price per orange paid by any customer or the largest total (not average) premium (above \$16 per orange) paid by any customer.